# Not able to import main app module in xctest

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, testing, xctest

When using XCTest I am not able to import the main module. Instead of like importing `@testable import App` it is import `@testable import Pods_App`, also not able to import the main app structs and data. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Click on your test file, then press CMD + OPTION + 0. This will bring up the inspector panel on the right side of the screen. Look for the target membership section inside the panel and ensure that the your test module is checked.

Comment: The test target membership is checked